# Why does my Redux props object return undefined?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux

I am trying to access a value within an object I'm getting from my Redux store.

Here's my Redux state:
[image]

I'm setting this on app load like this:

```
useEffect(() => {
    // Update the global state with the app content
    getContent().then(res => {
      props.updateContent(res);
    });
  }, []);
```

with an action:

```
export const updateContent = content => {
  return {
    type: "UPDATE",
    payload: content
  };
};
```

and a reducer:

```
const contentReducer = (state = {}, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case "UPDATE":
      return action.payload;
    default:
      return state;
  }
};

export default contentReducer;
```

However, when I try to log or access the `header_section`, I get `Cannot read property 'header_section' of undefined`. Which is strange, because I can log out just the content props object and see it's there.

Here's where I'm trying to access it:

```
const Header = props => {
  console.log("CONTENT-----", props.content.header_section);

  // simplified component
  return (
    <button>{props.content.header_section.cta_buy_ticket}</button>
  );
};

const mapStateToProps = state => {
  return {
    content: state.contentReducer.global_options
  };
};

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(Header);
```

Codesandbox here - https://codesandbox.io/s/thirsty-sid-ov65i?file=/src/App.js

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `mapStateToProps` picks `contentReducer.global_options` to be the `content` prop.

Your question indicates that you're trying to access `contentReducer.header_section` by doing `content.header_section`. In this case, you meant to return `state.contentReducer` as the `content` prop from `mapStateToProps`:

```
const mapStateToProps = state => {
  return {
    content: state.contentReducer
  };
};
```

Now you can access `props.content.header_options`, which refers to the same object as `state.contentReducer.header_options` in `mapStateToProps`.

If you still get the error, then `contentReducer`'s initial value is probably undefined. Either set an initial value with the same object shape as the data, or check that the keys you access exist before using them (e.g. `if (!props.content || !props.content.header_options) return null`)

Comment: Even if I make it `content: state.contentReducer` I'll still run into the same problem. In that case I'd be trying to access `props.content.global_options.header_section.cta_buy_ticket`. But I'll get the same error.

Comment: @G.Cox In the image of your redux state, the `header_section` is directly under `contentReducer`. Do you mean that the same key exists also under `global_options`? Again, if the data hasn't been fetched yet and you don't provide an initial state to redux which creates initial objects all the way (e.g. `contentReducer: { global_options: { header_section: { cta_buy_tick: null } } }`, the objects won't exist until the data has been fetched and the state has been updated.

Comment: Ah yes! You are correct, I'm not sure where I was seeing `global_options`, but I've removed it and fixed it. Thank you!